# Get value of mouse Y axis (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, html, variables, yaxis

I am making a game in JavaScript and I would like to define a variable as the Mouse Y axis. Please don't make the code un-necessarily complex if you can help it.
That's all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `addEventListener` for `"mousemove"`, which on each movement of mouse prints out it coordinates:

```js
document.addEventListener("mousemove", () => {
  let mousex = event.clientX; // Gets Mouse X
  let mousey = event.clientY; // Gets Mouse Y
  console.log([mousex, mousey]); // Prints data
});
```

Code credits: https://www.codegrepper.com/code-examples/javascript/how+to+get+mouse+x+and+y+in+javascript

Comment: No problem :) If you feel an answer solved the problem, please mark it as 'accepted' by clicking the green check mark.